# Allow special characters in Xelement.SetAttributeValue

Tags: c#, asp.net, xelement

I want to use special characters in the name of the attribute like ":" how can i do that?

`.SetAttributeValue("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");`

when i try it says that ":" is not allowed as a attribute name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
el.SetAttributeValue(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

Alternative syntax:

```
el.SetAttributeValue(XNamespace.Xmlns.GetName("xsi"), "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```